# Convert NSData bytes to custom object

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I am starting a project to create an iOS app to communicate with a device over BLE.  Being a new effort, I am trying to do this is Swift if possible.  The interface uses GATT and an existing set of custom message structures. I get to a point where I have the data from BLE in an `NSData` object.  I'd like to cast it or directly convert it to my message structure in a fairly generic way.

I know that I can extract the data by hand either directly from the byte array from the `NSData` object or using an `NSInputStream`. While that works, it could be a maintenance issue and the interface has a number of different messages in it.

Is there an easier ways to do this?

I'd be willing to create the message structures in Objective-C and do the casting there, but my knowledge of Objective-C is not much better than my knowledge of Swift.

Some sample code of what I've been playing in my playground is shown below.  It all works as expected.

```
func getBytesFromNSData(data: NSData, start: Int) -> [UInt8] {
    let count = data.length / sizeof(UInt8)
    let remaining = count - start
    let range = NSMakeRange(start, remaining )
    var dataArray = [UInt8](count: remaining, repeatedValue: 0)
    data.getBytes(&dataArray, range: range)
    return dataArray
}

class TestObject {
    var a: Byte
    var b: Byte

    init() {
        a = 0x01
        b = 0x02
    }

    init(data: NSData) {
        let dataBytes = getBytesFromNSData(data, 0)
        a = Byte(dataBytes[0])
        b = Byte(dataBytes[1])
    }

    func populateFromStream(data: NSData) {
        var stream = NSInputStream(data: data)
        stream.open()
        var bytesRead = stream.read(&a, maxLength: 1)
        println("\(bytesRead)")

        bytesRead = stream.read(&b, maxLength: 1)
        println("\(bytesRead)")
    }

    func toArray() -> [Byte] {
        var result = [Byte](count: 2, repeatedValue: 0)
        result[0] = a
        result[1] = b

        return result
    }
}

let test = TestObject()
let testArray = test.toArray()
let length = testArray.count
let testData = NSData(bytes: testArray, length: length)
println("\(testData)")

let testIn = [ Byte(0x0d), Byte(0x0e) ]
let testDataIn = NSData(bytes: testIn, length: testIn.count)
println("\(testDataIn)")

let testConstructor = TestObject(data: testDataIn)

var testObject = TestObject()
testObject.populateFromStream(testDataIn)
```

Comment: Understand that hardly anyone knows what sort of data structures GATT implies.  But the sort of dissassembly you apparently want to do is probably best performed in pure C, either by defining `struct`s to overlay the data or by reading individual bytes and assembling into the desired form.

Comment: That's the conclusion that I am coming to, but I was hoping someone might have a different answer.  Reading the individual bytes isn't hard in Swift, its just tedious.

Comment: Your best bet is to somehow come up with a standardized "style" with which you handle everything, vs ad-hoc.  Eg, write utility methods that give you an `int` or a `double` or whatever, starting at a given offset in the NSData object. Then write sequences of those to move to/from your internal structures.  Keep complex offset/length calculations to a minimum and keep them all in one spot.

Comment: can't you use NSKeyArchiver?

Comment: In this particular example, probably, but my real data structures are coming from a different device that uses 8-bit embedded processors running C.  The data will not come in a format compatible with NSKeyUnarchiver

Answer (score 0):

I found a method that is fairly generic that may work is some cases.

1. Create an Objective-C riding header
2. Create the data structure as an Objective-C structure
3. Import the header with the data structure into the bridging header
4. Assuming that you have a struct called `Foo` and an NSData object called `rawData`:

Use the following code to get an cast a pointer.

```
let structureSize = sizeof(Foo)
var myObject = UnsafeMutablePointer<Foo>.alloc(1).memory
rawData.getbytes(&myObject, length: structureSize)
```

This will not work in all instances and unfortunately does work in my particular case.  The specific problems I have found are:

- The Objective-C structure is word aligned.  If your structure is not properly aligned to work boundaries, you  may have a size that is incorrect.  (something I ran into in my particular interface)
- If you and dealing with a system that doesn't send the data in the same order you are expecting, this will not handle any byte order conversion, that would still need to be done and the structure would possibly need to be reordered to compensate.  That work might negate any saving from this method.

This is the most concise method I have found if it happens to work with your particular message formats.